# Activity leaked window exception on Dialog.show() when starting a Fragment transaction from an Activity class

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-dialog

When I click on the `CreateWorkout` button, it goes to the fragment `UserWorkoutPlanFragment()` class specified in the `FragmentTransaction`. But the moment transaction starts I get an error. 
I get this error:

```
05-22 19:23:35.873: E/WindowManager(1042): Activity com.fitserv.user.profilemenu.NewWorkout has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{4170dd80 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-308,96} that was originally added here
05-22 19:23:35.873: E/WindowManager(1042): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.fitserv.user.profilemenu.NewWorkout has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{4170dd80 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-308,96} that was originally added here
05-22 19:23:35.873: E/WindowManager(1042):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:354)
05-22 19:23:35.873: E/WindowManager(1042):  at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:216)
05-22 19:23:35.873: E/WindowManager(1042):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
05-22 19:23:35.873: E/WindowManager(1042):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281)
05-22 19:23:35.873: E/WindowManager(1042):  at com.fitserv.user.profilemenu.NewWorkout$NewWorkoutPlan.onPreExecute(NewWorkout.java:90)
05-22 19:23:35.873: E/WindowManager(1042):  at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
05-22 19:23:35.873: E/WindowManager(1042):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
05-22 19:23:35.873: E/WindowManager(1042):  at com.fitserv.user.profilemenu.NewWorkout$1.onClick(NewWorkout.java:70)
05-22 19:23:35.873: E/WindowManager(1042):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
05-22 19:23:35.873: E/WindowManager(1042):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
05-22 19:23:35.873: E/WindowManager(1042):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
05-22 19:23:35.873: E/WindowManager(1042):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-22 19:23:35.873: E/WindowManager(1042):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-22 19:23:35.873: E/WindowManager(1042):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
05-22 19:23:35.873: E/WindowManager(1042):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-22 19:23:35.873: E/WindowManager(1042):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-22 19:23:35.873: E/WindowManager(1042):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
05-22 19:23:35.873: E/WindowManager(1042):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
05-22 19:23:35.873: E/WindowManager(1042):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is my code:

```
public class NewWorkout extends Activity {

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    EditText inputWorkoutName;
    EditText inputWorkoutDate;
    EditText inputExceriseName;
    EditText inputSets;
    EditText inputKg;
    EditText inputReps;
    EditText inputNotes;


    // url to create new product
    private static String url_create_workout = "http://ec2-54-77-51-119.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/android_connect/create_workout.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.user_addworkout);

        // Edit Text
        inputWorkoutName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputWorkoutName);
        inputWorkoutDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputWorkoutDate);
        inputExceriseName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputExceriseName);
        inputSets = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSets);
        inputKg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputKg);
        inputReps = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputReps);
        inputNotes = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputNotes);

        // Create button
        Button btnCreateWorkout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCreateWorkout);
        // button click event
        btnCreateWorkout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // creating new product in background thread
                new NewWorkoutPlan().execute();
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Create new product
     * */
    class NewWorkoutPlan extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(NewWorkout.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Creating Your Workout Plan..");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Creating product
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            String workout_name = inputWorkoutName.getText().toString();
            String workout_date = inputWorkoutDate.getText().toString();
            String exercise_name = inputExceriseName.getText().toString();
            String sets = inputSets.getText().toString();
            String weight_kg = inputKg.getText().toString();
            String reps = inputReps.getText().toString();
            String notes = inputNotes.getText().toString();

            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("workout_name", workout_name));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("workout_date", workout_date));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("exercise_name", exercise_name));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sets", sets));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("weight_kg", weight_kg));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("reps", reps));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("notes", notes));

            // getting JSON Object
            // Note that create product url accepts POST method
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_workout,
                    "POST", params);

            // check log cat fro response
            Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

            // check for success tag
            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    /**
                    // successfully created product
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UserProfileActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    //closing this screen
                    finish();
                    **/

                    Fragment newFragment = new UserWorkoutPlanFragment();
                      FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                       transaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, newFragment);
                        transaction.commit();

                    UserWorkoutPlanFragment fd = new UserWorkoutPlanFragment();
                      FragmentTransaction  ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                                  ft.replace(R.id.frame_container, fd); 

                                 // content_frame is your FrameLayout container
                                  ft.addToBackStack(null);
                                  ft.commit();  

                } else {
                    // failed to create product
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once done
            pDialog.dismiss();

        }

    }
}
```

Can someone please help me out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

pDialog is causing the window leak. That is happening because you are doing the fragment transaction in in doInBackground and calling the **dismiss** method onPostExecute.

You should post the transaction code in onPostExecute after calling **dismiss**

Comment: how would i go about doing that?

Comment: I see you are relying on an integer variable 'success'. You could declare your asynctask like AsyncTask<String, String, int> and then return the 'success' variable in doInBackGround which would be automatically received by onPostExecute. Then you can check this value and call the transaction code.

Comment: im not getting this error anymore, however I'm now getting an "no view found for id" error heres the link to the question, please help me have a look. here the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30412630/no-view-found-for-id-0x7f0900ad-when-performing-fragment-transaction) to the question

Answer (score 0):

I know that you are new in Android, but maybe you have already developed in other language, haven't you? Anyway, you should code using design patterns and do what you wanna do in its own specific class. Doing so, you'll avoid many errors like that one.
Take a look this website about design patterns: http://pt.slideshare.net/PedroVicenteGmezSnch/software-design-patterns-on-android

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute the `FragmentTransaction` in the UI thread. It can be done from within `doInBackground` method by calling `runOnUiThread`:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Fragment newFragment = new UserWorkoutPlanFragment();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, newFragment);
        transaction.commit();

        UserWorkoutPlanFragment fd = new UserWorkoutPlanFragment();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.frame_container, fd);

        // content_frame is your FrameLayout container
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();

    }
});
```

Comment: now I'm getting an error  No view found for id 0x7f0900a3 (com.fitserv.androidapp:id/frame_container) for fragment UserWorkoutPlanFragment{40d0b748 #0 id=0x7f0900a3}, do you know why this might be the case

Comment: @user3661128 it's an unrelated error. Please ask another question.

Comment: yea i did, here the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30412630/no-view-found-for-id-0x7f0900ad-when-performing-fragment-transaction)

Comment: @user3661128 , If the posted answer helped you in anyway, simply click as the best answer or vote as helpful only. I think you did made the code changes suggested above.

Answer (score 0):

In the logcat error, there is:

> at
>   com.fitserv.user.profilemenu.NewWorkout$NewWorkoutPlan.**onPreExecute**(NewWorkout.java:90)
>   05-22 19:23:35.873: E/WindowManager(1042):  at
>   android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)

So the problem is at **onPreExecute** method. I have not used ProgressDialog before but the issue is on the context parameter. in this case `NewWorkout.this`. It's not the correct context.

Code suggestions:

1. pDialog = new ProgressDialog( getApplicationContext() );
2. pDialog = new ProgressDialog( getActivity() );
3. pDialog = new
   ProgressDialog( MainActivity.this );

Note: For MainActivity, you can use this code if it is declared as `static`.
The main issue, I think, is the **context**.

FYI: I find it interesting that the posted answers are somewhat different but some are concentrating on the dialog.

Comment: I'm now getting an "no view found for id" error heres the link to the question, please help me have a look. here the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30412630/no-view-found-for-id-0x7f0900ad-when-performing-fragment-transaction) to the question