# No view found for id 0x7f0900ad when performing fragment transaction

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, illegalargumentexception, android-framelayout

When I try to start a fragment from an activity class I keep getting a

`No view found for id 0x7f0900ad frame_container2` error. The code then crashes after progress dialog shows up and moves to the fragment I'm trying to starting.

When it crashes it gives me an error like this:

```
    05-23 12:02:32.271: E/FragmentManager(4295): No view found for id 0x7f0900ad (com.fitserv.androidapp:id/frame_container2) for fragment UserWorkoutPlanFragment{4165dbc8 #0 id=0x7f0900ad}
05-23 12:02:32.271: E/FragmentManager(4295): Activity state:
05-23 12:02:32.281: E/FragmentManager(4295):   Local Activity 40cdf1d0 State:
05-23 12:02:32.291: E/FragmentManager(4295):     mResumed=true mStopped=false mFinished=false
05-23 12:02:32.291: E/FragmentManager(4295):     mLoadersStarted=true
05-23 12:02:32.291: E/FragmentManager(4295):     mChangingConfigurations=false
05-23 12:02:32.301: E/FragmentManager(4295):     mCurrentConfig={1.0 310mcc260mnc en_US ldltr sw320dp w320dp h407dp 160dpi smll port finger qwerty/v/v -nav/h s.6}
05-23 12:02:32.301: E/FragmentManager(4295):   Active Fragments in 40d72310:
05-23 12:02:32.331: E/FragmentManager(4295):     #0: UserWorkoutPlanFragment{4165dbc8 #0 id=0x7f0900ad}
05-23 12:02:32.331: E/FragmentManager(4295):       mFragmentId=#7f0900ad mContainerId=#7f0900ad mTag=null
05-23 12:02:32.341: E/FragmentManager(4295):       mState=0 mIndex=0 mWho=android:fragment:0 mBackStackNesting=1
05-23 12:02:32.341: E/FragmentManager(4295):       mAdded=true mRemoving=false mResumed=false mFromLayout=false mInLayout=false
05-23 12:02:32.351: E/FragmentManager(4295):       mHidden=false mDetached=false mMenuVisible=true mHasMenu=false
05-23 12:02:32.351: E/FragmentManager(4295):       mRetainInstance=false mRetaining=false mUserVisibleHint=true
05-23 12:02:32.351: E/FragmentManager(4295):       mFragmentManager=FragmentManager{40d72310 in NewWorkout{40cdf1d0}}
05-23 12:02:32.361: E/FragmentManager(4295):       mActivity=com.fitserv.user.profilemenu.NewWorkout@40cdf1d0
05-23 12:02:32.361: E/FragmentManager(4295):   Added Fragments:
05-23 12:02:32.361: E/FragmentManager(4295):     #0: UserWorkoutPlanFragment{4165dbc8 #0 id=0x7f0900ad}
05-23 12:02:32.361: E/FragmentManager(4295):   Back Stack Indices:
05-23 12:02:32.381: E/FragmentManager(4295):     #0: BackStackEntry{4165dd08 #0}
05-23 12:02:32.381: E/FragmentManager(4295):   FragmentManager misc state:
05-23 12:02:32.401: E/FragmentManager(4295):     mActivity=com.fitserv.user.profilemenu.NewWorkout@40cdf1d0
05-23 12:02:32.401: E/FragmentManager(4295):     mContainer=android.app.Activity$1@416459b8
05-23 12:02:32.411: E/FragmentManager(4295):     mCurState=5 mStateSaved=false mDestroyed=false
05-23 12:02:32.411: E/FragmentManager(4295):   View Hierarchy:
05-23 12:02:32.421: E/FragmentManager(4295):     com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{40d45ed0 V.E..... R.....I. 0,0-320,432}
05-23 12:02:32.421: E/FragmentManager(4295):       android.widget.LinearLayout{416ae1d8 V.E..... ......I. 0,0-320,432}
05-23 12:02:32.431: E/FragmentManager(4295):         com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer{40d5aba8 V.ED.... ......I. 0,25-320,73 #1020359 android:id/action_bar_container}
05-23 12:02:32.431: E/FragmentManager(4295):           com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView{40d27848 V.E..... ......I. 0,0-320,48 #102035a android:id/action_bar}
05-23 12:02:32.441: E/FragmentManager(4295):             android.widget.LinearLayout{40d47ae0 V.....C. ......I. 9,0-113,48}
05-23 12:02:32.451: E/FragmentManager(4295):               com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView$HomeView{40d59f60 V.E..... ......I. 0,0-40,48}
05-23 12:02:32.451: E/FragmentManager(4295):                 android.widget.ImageView{40d29198 G.ED.... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #1020246 android:id/up}
05-23 12:02:32.461: E/FragmentManager(4295):                 android.widget.ImageView{4168f1c8 V.ED.... ......I. 4,8-36,40 #102002c android:id/home}
05-23 12:02:32.461: E/FragmentManager(4295):               android.widget.LinearLayout{4169c5b0 V.E..... ......I. 40,0-104,48}
05-23 12:02:32.471: E/FragmentManager(4295):                 android.widget.ImageView{40d28350 G.ED.... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #1020246 android:id/up}
05-23 12:02:32.491: E/FragmentManager(4295):                 android.widget.LinearLayout{40d56b88 V.E..... ......I. 0,11-56,36}
05-23 12:02:32.491: E/FragmentManager(4295):                   android.widget.TextView{40d44580 V.ED.... ......I. 0,0-56,25 #102024d android:id/action_bar_title}
05-23 12:02:32.491: E/FragmentManager(4295):                   android.widget.TextView{40d474f8 G.ED.... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #102024e android:id/action_bar_subtitle}
05-23 12:02:32.501: E/FragmentManager(4295):             com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuView{40d24448 V.ED.... ......ID 320,0-320,48}
05-23 12:02:32.511: E/FragmentManager(4295):           com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContextView{40d57b78 G.E..... ......ID 0,0-0,0 #102035b android:id/action_context_bar}
05-23 12:02:32.521: E/FragmentManager(4295):         android.widget.FrameLayout{41658cd8 V.ED.... ......I. 0,73-320,432 #1020002 android:id/content}
05-23 12:02:32.531: E/FragmentManager(4295):           android.widget.ScrollView{41645e50 VFED.V.. ......I. 0,0-320,359}
05-23 12:02:32.531: E/FragmentManager(4295):             android.widget.LinearLayout{40d61190 V.E..... ......I. 0,0-320,587}
05-23 12:02:32.531: E/FragmentManager(4295):               android.widget.TextView{40d48360 V.ED.... ......I. 0,0-320,33}
05-23 12:02:32.551: E/FragmentManager(4295):               android.widget.EditText{40d1da60 VFED..CL ......I. 5,38-315,63 #7f09008b app:id/inputWorkoutName}
05-23 12:02:32.551: E/FragmentManager(4295):               android.widget.TextView{40d1e588 V.ED.... ......I. 0,68-320,101}
05-23 12:02:32.581: E/FragmentManager(4295):               android.widget.EditText{40d1fb60 VFED..CL ......I. 5,106-315,131 #7f09008c app:id/inputWorkoutDate}
05-23 12:02:32.581: E/FragmentManager(4295):               android.widget.TextView{40d448d8 V.ED.... ......I. 0,136-320,169}
05-23 12:02:32.591: E/FragmentManager(4295):               android.widget.EditText{40d469e8 VFED..CL ......I. 5,174-315,199 #7f09008d app:id/inputExceriseName}
05-23 12:02:32.601: E/FragmentManager(4295):               android.widget.TextView{40d465d8 V.ED.... ......I. 0,204-320,237}
05-23 12:02:32.601: E/FragmentManager(4295):               android.widget.EditText{40d4af38 VFED..CL .F....I. 5,242-315,267 #7f09008e app:id/inputSets}
05-23 12:02:32.601: E/FragmentManager(4295):               android.widget.TextView{416947d8 V.ED.... ......I. 0,272-320,305}
05-23 12:02:32.611: E/FragmentManager(4295):               android.widget.EditText{40d23090 VFED..CL ......I. 5,310-315,335 #7f09008f app:id/inputKg}
05-23 12:02:32.621: E/FragmentManager(4295):               android.widget.TextView{40d486b8 V.ED.... ......I. 0,340-320,373}
05-23 12:02:32.621: E/FragmentManager(4295):               android.widget.EditText{4168f578 VFED..CL ......I. 5,378-315,403 #7f090090 app:id/inputReps}
05-23 12:02:32.621: E/FragmentManager(4295):               android.widget.TextView{4168fd90 V.ED.... ......I. 0,408-320,441}
05-23 12:02:32.631: E/FragmentManager(4295):               android.widget.EditText{416900a8 VFED..CL ......I. 5,446-315,534 #7f090091 app:id/inputNotes}
05-23 12:02:32.641: E/FragmentManager(4295):               android.widget.Button{416cc998 VFED..C. ......I. 0,539-320,587 #7f090092 app:id/btnCreateWorkout}
05-23 12:02:32.660: E/FragmentManager(4295):         com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer{41664298 G.ED.... ......ID 0,0-0,0 #102035c android:id/split_action_bar}
05-23 12:02:32.660: D/AndroidRuntime(4295): Shutting down VM
05-23 12:02:32.660: W/dalvikvm(4295): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
05-23 12:02:32.691: E/AndroidRuntime(4295): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-23 12:02:32.691: E/AndroidRuntime(4295): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0900ad (com.fitserv.androidapp:id/frame_container2) for fragment UserWorkoutPlanFragment{4165dbc8 #0 id=0x7f0900ad}
05-23 12:02:32.691: E/AndroidRuntime(4295):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:877)
05-23 12:02:32.691: E/AndroidRuntime(4295):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1057)
05-23 12:02:32.691: E/AndroidRuntime(4295):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
05-23 12:02:32.691: E/AndroidRuntime(4295):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1435)
05-23 12:02:32.691: E/AndroidRuntime(4295):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:441)
05-23 12:02:32.691: E/AndroidRuntime(4295):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
05-23 12:02:32.691: E/AndroidRuntime(4295):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-23 12:02:32.691: E/AndroidRuntime(4295):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-23 12:02:32.691: E/AndroidRuntime(4295):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
05-23 12:02:32.691: E/AndroidRuntime(4295):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-23 12:02:32.691: E/AndroidRuntime(4295):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-23 12:02:32.691: E/AndroidRuntime(4295):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
05-23 12:02:32.691: E/AndroidRuntime(4295):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
05-23 12:02:32.691: E/AndroidRuntime(4295):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is my NewWorkout class, that performing the FragmentTransaction:

```
public class NewWorkout extends Activity {

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    EditText inputWorkoutName;
    EditText inputWorkoutDate;
    EditText inputExceriseName;
    EditText inputSets;
    EditText inputKg;
    EditText inputReps;
    EditText inputNotes;


    // url to create new product
    private static String url_create_workout = "http://ec2-54-77-51-119.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/android_connect/create_workout.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.user_addworkout);

        // Edit Text
        inputWorkoutName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputWorkoutName);
        inputWorkoutDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputWorkoutDate);
        inputExceriseName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputExceriseName);
        inputSets = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSets);
        inputKg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputKg);
        inputReps = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputReps);
        inputNotes = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputNotes);

        // Create button
        Button btnCreateWorkout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCreateWorkout);
        // button click event
        btnCreateWorkout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // creating new product in background thread
                new NewWorkoutPlan().execute();
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Create new product
     * */
    class NewWorkoutPlan extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(NewWorkout.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Creating Your Workout Plan..");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Creating product
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            String workout_name = inputWorkoutName.getText().toString();
            String workout_date = inputWorkoutDate.getText().toString();
            String exercise_name = inputExceriseName.getText().toString();
            String sets = inputSets.getText().toString();
            String weight_kg = inputKg.getText().toString();
            String reps = inputReps.getText().toString();
            String notes = inputNotes.getText().toString();

            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("workout_name", workout_name));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("workout_date", workout_date));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("exercise_name", exercise_name));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sets", sets));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("weight_kg", weight_kg));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("reps", reps));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("notes", notes));

            // getting JSON Object
            // Note that create product url accepts POST method
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_workout,
                    "POST", params);

            // check log cat fro response
            Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

            // check for success tag
            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    /**
                    // successfully created product
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UserProfileActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    //closing this screen
                    finish();
                    **/ 
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                           @Override
                           public void run() {
                                UserWorkoutPlanFragment fd = new UserWorkoutPlanFragment();
                                FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                                ft.replace(R.id.frame_container2, fd);
                                ft.addToBackStack(null);
                                ft.commit();
                            }

                        });

             } else {
                    // failed to create product
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once done

            pDialog.dismiss();


        }

    }
}
```

here my UserWorkoutPlanFragment class:

```
public class UserWorkoutPlanFragment extends ListFragment {


    Button CreateWorkout;
    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> workoutsList;

    // url to get all workouts list
    private static String url_all_workouts = "http://ec2-54-77-51-119.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/android_connect/get_all_workouts.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_WORKOUT = "workoutplan";
    private static final String TAG_WID = "wid";
    private static final String TAG_WORKOUT_NAME = "workout_name";
    private static final String TAG_WORKOUT_DATE = "workout_date";

 // workouts JSONArray
    JSONArray workout = null;

    public UserWorkoutPlanFragment(){}

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.user_workoutplan, container, false);

        // Buttons
         CreateWorkout = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.createworkout);

        // create workouts click event
         CreateWorkout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Launching create new workouts activity
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), NewWorkout.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
         return rootView;
    }

    @Override 
     public void onViewCreated (View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //List workout 

         workoutsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Loading workouts in Background Thread
        new LoadAllWorkouts().execute();

        // Get listview
        // Get listview
            ListView lv = getListView();

            // on seleting single product
            // launching Edit Product Screen
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    // getting values from selected ListItem
                    String wid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.wid)).getText()
                            .toString();

                    // Starting new intent
                    Intent in = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                            EditWorkouts.class);
                    // sending pid to next activity
                    in.putExtra(TAG_WID, wid);

                    // starting new activity and expecting some response back
                    startActivityForResult(in, 100);
                }
            });
    }
    // Response from Edit Product Activity
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // if result code 100
        if (resultCode == 100) {
            // if result code 100 is received 
            // means user edited/deleted product
            // reload this screen again
            Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
            getActivity().finish();
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
     * */
    class LoadAllWorkouts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading your workouts, Please wait...");
            //pDialog.setMessage("almost done...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * getting All products from url
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_workouts, "GET", params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("All Workouts: ", json.toString());

            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // products found
                    // Getting Array of Workout
                    workout = json.getJSONArray(TAG_WORKOUT);

                    // looping through All Workout
                    for (int i = 0; i < workout.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = workout.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        String id = c.getString(TAG_WID);
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_WORKOUT_NAME);
                        String date = c.getString(TAG_WORKOUT_DATE);

                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_WID, id);
                        map.put(TAG_WORKOUT_NAME, name);
                        map.put(TAG_WORKOUT_DATE, date);

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        workoutsList.add(map);
                    }
                } else {
                    // no workout found
                    // Launch Add New workout Activity
                    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(),
                            NewWorkout.class);
                    // Closing all previous activities
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all workouts
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter( getActivity(), workoutsList, R.layout.list_item,
                            new String[] { TAG_WID, TAG_WORKOUT_NAME, TAG_WORKOUT_DATE},
                            new int[] { R.id.wid, R.id.workout_name , R.id.workout_date});
                    // updating listview
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });

        }

    }

}
```

Does anyone have any idea how I could resolve this issue?

Comment: Is this where the crash happens at code "...fd = new UserWorkoutPlanFragment()"? Pls post code for UserWorkoutPlanFragment class.

Comment: What an empty constructor doing in you fragment class?

Comment: Please first answer my question. Where is it crashing? Remember we don't have the full code and don't know the exact code where it crashed on the debugger.

Comment: @TheOriginalAndroid Yes the code is crashing at new UserWorkoutPlanFragment()

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to extend **ListFragment** in:

```
public class UserWorkoutPlanFragment extends ListFragment...
```

If you do extend ListFragment, you have to reference xml layout containing a ListView element. So the code in `onCreateView` pointing to an xml layout:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.user_workoutplan, container, false);
```

Notes:

- Layout `user_workoutplan` must include a **ListView** element. Otherwise, extending ListFragment is useless. I think that is the problem.
- Again, another solution is to not extend **ListFragment**.

Good luck in this project. The existing code such at is now is not easy to understand. And there are codes that I think is suspect or should change.